# Save collapsible state on jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery tabs with the collapsible option. I was wondering how to save the state of my collapsible option (maximized or minimized) across subsequent requests(page loads), within a cookie. The ideas is if I refresh the page and the tab was minimized then i should see it minimized.

Comment: what do you mean by *"subsequent requests"*? page loads? ajax requests?

Comment: You've put a bounty on this, while an answer with 6 upvotes is sitting there.  What's your problem with the existing answer?

Comment: My tabs are requested through ajax, so when i use the cookie a blank tab appears. And i cannot parse the url to find out which tab is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Other than cookies?

You can of course use cookies, but there are other ways of doing it as well:

- local storage as known in modern browsers
- old hack of using `window.name` as explained and used in [this tiny simple small library](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) by Thomas Frank.

Just sayin' you can use other means as well that preserve upon full page requests...

Answer (score 13):

you can use the `cookie` option built right into the plugin, Initialize a tabs with the cookie option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```

Get or set the cookie option, after init.

```
//getter
var cookie = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "cookie" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "cookie", { expires: 30 } );
```

## [**DOCS**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-cookie)

Comment: To do that, the cookie plugin is required

Answer (score 1):

maybe give hash method a go!

use this plugin
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
(you don't really need it, but it save you writing a few more line)

When you click on expand, it should add the #hash.class to url

than you determine if the window.location has class if it does, expand it.

But this method only work with one maximising at a time.